# Access static files on server from RCL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, static-files, razor-class-library

I've read dozens of questions but none seem to work for me. I'm not using IIS. I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1 with Kestrel.

I have a Razor Class Library with a resources folder, in that I have folders like css, js, content, etc. I use this library so all of my common Web Api projects can share common files instead of duplicating them everywhere. To do this, I followed the guide from [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/330/including-static-resources-in-razor-class-libraries-in-asp-net-core). Please see there for how Startup is configured.

That works great, I can access those files by going to e.g. `localhost/css/site.css`. In my cshtml files, I can include that file by doing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css"/>`

The problem arises when I try to access those files from a controller. I have a sister folder to css called content which contains json files. I can view that file by going to `localhost/content/test.json`, but I can't figure out how to access it from a controller.

What I'd like to do is make an HTTP request to `~/content/test.json` and download its contents, but the path is not found.

I've tried using `Url.Content` to map a relative path to the absolute path, but it doesn't work.

`var url = Url.Content("~/content/test.json"); // spits out "/content/test.json"`

I've DI'd `IWebHostEnvironment` into the controller and tried to access the `ContentRootFileProvider` and the `ContentRootPath` and `WebRootPath`, but those paths aren't right either. They are pointing to my currently running service's wwwroot's parent and wwwroot, respectively.

I've tried creating my own file provider:

```
var filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, "resources");
var content = filesProvider.GetDirectoryContents("content");
var fileInfo = filesProvider.GetFileInfo(Path.Combine("content", "test.json"));
```

This successfully finds the file and claims it exists, but the `fileInfo`'s `PhysicalPath` is always `null`.

I just want to do something like this:

```
string SomeMagicMapFunction(string s) => ????

var webClient = new WebClient();
var json = webClient.DownloadString(SomeMagicMapFunction("~/content/test.json"));
```

Where am I going wrong? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets

Comment: Thanks for reading. I've always glanced over that since the author of the article I linked says he avoided calling the resources folder "wwwroot" since the files are embedded resources. I just tried creating wwwroot in the RCL but I couldn't find a way to access them, only 404s back. My current approach can retrieve the files, but must use an absolute URL. I'm essentially looking for IIS's `Server.MapPath` but a .NET Core equivalent. The way I'm getting around this for now is `var url = Request.Scheme+"://"+string.Join('/', Request.Host.Value,"content","test.json");` but it doesn't feel right.

Comment: Ah! I think you're looking to override the default StaticFileOptions. Check this one out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root

Comment: I tried playing around with this but still couldn't get it to work. I think I may already be serving static files from my resources dir since I have `services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureOptions>()` where `ConfigureOptions::PostConfigure` sets a new file provider (as seen in the tutorial I linked). That, and I can access the files via the absolute path, or via the relative path `~/css/site.css` but only in cshtml files. Doing similar in a controller fails to find it. Maybe I need to make a DI'able `IFileServerProvider` I can use in the controller to map back to the physical path? ie: /a/43340432

Comment: For example in my cshtml if I do an ajax call to `url: '/content/test.json',` I can retrieve the json. But trying to make a web request in the controller fails unless I manually build the absolute path. Does this mean my static files are configured correctly, and there is a separate issue with access from C# side (like needing a custom FileProvider to be DI'd)? Or would this be a static file configuration issue. I'm new to all this web stuff so I'm still trying to get familiar with it all.

Comment: So yes, I read the article you started from. It also says near the bottom that there's an open github issue to improve the experience. That issue has been resolved and implemented! The docs for that, I have already shared in these comments. I suggest you follow the new stuff!  Not to discredit the author, there weren't any other options in the NetCore 2.1 days but to pioneer some of these things.

Comment: Alright, so I removed the `ConfigureOptions` code and am now only using `UseStaticFiles` but the `IWebHostEnvironment` is always relevant to the currently running service, I need it to be relevant to the RCL. How can I get the RCL's web host when I call `UseStaticFiles`? And then when I expose that in my controller and return a `PhysicalFile`, I guess that provides an endpoint to direct download my json, but how can I use that from another function in the same controller? Is there a way to just get that content instead of doing a web request?

Comment: oof! I missed this one.  How about instead of `/content/`, you use `/_content/` ?? that's another convention. That should work out of the box for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development`   when you're ready for prod, you'll need to add `UseStaticWebAssets()` to your IHostConfig.

Comment: Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I got this working the proper way. I had to make a `wwwroot` folder in my RCL and call `app.UseStaticFiles();` I can access the files through `/content` via absolute URLs. In the controller the DI'd `IWebHostEnvironment` contains both the RCL and the current project in its `WebRootFileProvider`. I get the physical path and call `File.ReadAllText` to process it. I'm not sure how this works for deploying/publishing yet (reading disk vs web request), but I think as long as I call `UseStaticWebAssets()` it should work, as you mentioned. 1/2

Comment: In order for the `PhysicalPath` to not be null, I had to add a property group in my RCL.csproj containing `<StaticWebAssetBasePath Condition="$(StaticWebAssetBasePath) == ''">/</StaticWebAssetBasePath>`. Now call my views/pages and static assets are shared as expected. 2/2